# How to replace one character at a specific index in a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a program which takes in a string as a command line argument. I then want to go into this string and replace one character with another at a specific index. So for a more concrete example, this is what I have and what I want to do:

```
string input(argv[2]); //lets say I run with ./Prog x bbbbbbb
//I want to do this
input.at(2) = "a"; //obviously this doesn't work
```

When I try `input.insert(2,a);`, and `cout << input` I get `bb$bbbbb` followed by a seg fault message on the next line. I initially thought I could insert at 2 and erase at 3 to replace the 3rd b with an a, but the seg fault ruins this for me. So is there any other way I can do this, or help me understand why I'm getting a seg fault?

edit: the seg fault was something else, but still I'm getting $ when attempting to input an a

Comment: _@OP_ _"edit: the seg fault was something else, but still I'm getting $ when attempting to input an a"_ did you mean `"a"` here actually? WTH is `a` in context of `input.insert(2,a);` please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"So for a more concrete example, this is what I have and what I want to do: ...*
>
> *... So is there any other way I can do this, or help me understand why I'm getting a seg fault?"*
>
> ```
> //I want to do this
> input.at(2) = "a"; //obviously this doesn't work
> ```

It doesn't work, because `"a"` actually provides a `const char*` pointer, and not a `char` as required by [`std::string::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at).
Use a simple character literal, not a c-style string literal:

```
 input.at(2) = 'a';
            // ^^^
```

---

> *"When I try `input.insert(2,a);`, and `cout << input` I get `bb$bbbbb` followed by a seg fault message on the next line."*

Besides [`std::string::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) doesn't provide *replacement* of a character at the given position, but *inserts* one or more characters there, you may have an uninitialized `char* a` passed here, causing a segfault. But to answer this part finally, you should specify what the variable `a` actually is in this context.